# Log boomerang parameters

Tags: boomerang, rum

I have been trying to implement real user monitoring for my website using boomerang JS. I used an old version of boomerang JS that sent the beacon requests using request type as "GET", but using the new version of boomerang it sends data using a "POST" request with the RUM data as "Form data parameters". I have been trying to build the beacon request in the form of a string having query parameters. For example : https://www.example.org/beacon?nt_start=1234&nt_nav=5678....

According to the boomerang documentation and source code provided at Github, if the request parameters have a length more than 2000 characters, it automatically forms a "POST" request, else it forms a "GET" request. But when I tried the implementation, it always formed a "POST" request by default even though my characters length was less than 2000. Is there any way to solve this, make boomerang send it in a "GET" request with query parameters. I plan to log them in a text file for future references.

[image]

Comment: Did you already post this on the boomerang issues list or on gitter chat? I somehow remember exactly this message. If not, that is the best place for boomerang questions. We try not to split the answers to questions across multiple sites.

Edit: found this: https://github.com/SOASTA/boomerang/issues/199

Comment: @bluesmoon Thanks for the quick reference.